# Display a specific data for User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem similar to this topic http://forums.asp.net/t/1763534.aspx/1

I have to show data to customers based on their username. I do not create a new topic because I've done that long ago and nobody has responded. I ask you because you seem to know it more than others ...

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MembershipUser currentUser = 
        Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);


    ViewBag.UsersRecord = currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    var details = from t in db.Employes
                  where t.UserId ==ViewBag.UsersRecord
                  select t;

    return View(details.ToList());

}
```

Strangely, Visual Studio shows me an error here

```
where t.UserId == ViewBag.UsersRecord
```

> "An expression tree may not Contain dinamyc in operation"

I've done something wrong?

Comment: Sorry but am new to stackoverflow and I knew that he must do so every time. I took all my answers, it should be fine.

Comment: That's okay - just wanted to point this out to you - it's not obvious when you start on SO. You're doing great - enjoy SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dynamic, since dynamic is determined at compile time.
try:

```
Guid userId = (Guid)ViewBag.UsersRecord;

var details = from t in db.Employes
                  where t.UserId == userId.ToString() //if you are using a string guid, otherwise remove ToString()
                  select t;

//or simply

var details = from t in db.Employes
                  where t.UserId == (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey
                  select t;
```

I don't know what your UserId is (type wise) so can't give you a 100% answer here

Comment: UserId i a GUID type. I need to compare with UserId Employe ID to show only the data with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
where t.UserId == new Guid(ViewBag.UsersRecord.ToString());
```